# Why is this address 0xFFFFFFFF?

Tags: c++, memory, lambda, c++20

In my .h file:

```
extern std::vector<bool*> selectedContainer;

inline void InitSprite(Sprite* sprite)
{
    bool* selected = new bool(false);
    sprite->onMouseHover = [&](){
        *selected = true;
    };
    sprite->onMouseNotHover = [&](){
        *selected = false;
    };
    selectedContainer.push_back(selected);
}
```

If for example the **onMouseHover** of the passed sprite gets called. The selected pointer is always 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Your lambdas should capture by value, not by reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why did the reference not work?

Comment: Because it captures a reference to `selected`, which is destroyed when the function returns, so the reference becomes dangling.

Comment: Capturing by reference is okay as long as the lambda is only local and doesn't escape.  In this code, the lambdas escape (because they are set to an external object).

Comment: OT: a vector of pointers to bool looks very wrong to me, why not store just bools? Like `std::vector<bool*>` -> `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: So i can keep track of them and be able to delete them later. I don't want to leak memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[&](){
```

The `&` means that the lambda captures its object by ***reference***.

```
bool* selected = new bool(false);
```

This declares `selected` in automatic scope. This means that when this function returns `selected` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. Note that this means that the ***pointer*** itself is destroyed, and that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with whatever the pointer is pointing to.

This pointer is captured by ***reference***, so after this function returns any time the lambda referenced the captured object it will end up referencing a destroyed object, hence the undefined behavior.

The simplest solution is to have the lambdas capture objects by ***value*** (by default):

```
[=](){
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sadly i can't upvote :(

Comment: @GeroB. I will for you :)